# Failed to start snmpd.service

Tags: snmp

I just installed net-snmp on Ubuntu 16.04 from sources using [this tutorial](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Net-Snmp_on_Ubuntu) (downloaded [5.7 patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/code/ci/V5-7-patches/tree/)), and when calling

```
$ snmpget --version
NET-SNMP version 5.7.3
$ whereis snmpd
snmpd: /usr/local/sbin/snmpd
```

so it has been installed. However, when I want to check if `snmpd` is running

```
sudo service snmpd status
```

it returns `Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory) Active: inactive (dead)`. When I try to start `snmpd`

```
sudo service snmpd start
```

it returns `Failed to start snmpd.service: Unit snmpd.service not found`. When starting it directly from command line

```
$ snmpd
snmpd: symbol lookup error: snmpd: Undefined symbol: netsnmpd_close_fds
```

The other problem is that the `/etc/snmp/` directory does not exist, which should contain the `snmpd.conf` file that I need to edit.

I never had these kinds of problems when I was using the

```
sudo apt-get install snmpd
```

but I must use sources to configure the installation with options that do not come with the 'apt-get' installation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the snmp:

```
sudo apt-get -y autoremove snmp
```

Install again like this:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Remove any unnecessary files shown in the system:

```
apt-get install snmpd
cat /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
systemctl restart snmpd
systemctl enable snmpd
systemctl status snmpd
```